# Visual Studio 2010 acting strange

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Yesterday my website solution still worked perfectly fine.

Today I get about 8 errors.

One of them being the `Using System.Linq;`

Another one being not recognising is the 'var'. giving some namespace error on it.

the last thing is that it suddenly doesn't know the script manager..

I know there's an easy way to fix this by simply creating a new project, and moving all the files over. But I want to know what is causing this, because there's no reason it should work 1 day and not the other...

**Assumption**

I'm assuming an reference of some sort just went missing...

**Update**

It is set to build in .net 4.0

I installed the asp.net 2.0 Source code for the build in Providers that's all.

I already reinstalled the whole visual studio with all it's components.

**Update2**

Somehow confirming in the properties page to use .net 4.0 it resolved my System.Linq problem..

Only problems left now is the 'var' and the script manager...

Comment: sounds to me like a computer corruption, or else .net corruption, try either reinstalling the .net framework or a system resore

Comment: So what did you do since yesterday? You could always revert back to previous version from your source control. You do use source control, don't you?

Comment: I do, but as I said I want to know what is causing this..

What I did yesterday was installing the .net2.0 Source code for the build-in providers.

Answer (score 0):

Since those are .net 4.0 elements it's possible that you're not building the site against .net 4.0 and that you're actually attempting to build against a lower version of .net, if you right click on the project in vs 2010 and click properties you should be able to check this.

Comment: Just checked and it said it's using .net 4.0